# Replacing object property name with different identifier

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

Here's the thing.. I want to overwite an object with if-else condition inside angular.forEach with this controller, basically "k1" has an original keyword and I want to replace it with a new keyword. what do you think is the best way to display the new input object?

```
$scope.SubmitKeyword = function (key, new_keyword) {
    console.log(key, new_keyword)
    $scope.new_keyword = new_keyword;

    if ($scope.new_keyword == null || $scope.new_keyword == undefined || $scope.new_keyword == "") {
        alert('Invalid input!')
        return
    }

    angular.forEach($scope.new_campaign_keywords, function (v, k) {
        console.log(v,k)
        if (k == key) {
            if (v['orig_keyword'] == new_keyword) {
                alert('No Changes Found!')
                return              
            } else {        
                console.log('changes detected')
                var a = 0;  
                angular.forEach($scope.campaigns, function (v1,k1) {
                    a++
                    console.log(k1)
                    if (k1 == a) {                      
                        //display the new keyword
                        else {
                            //remain the original keyword
                            }
                            }           
                })
            }
            }   
        })

    };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na9Qe.png)
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBmbU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method to detect the existence of a property:

```
$scope.SubmitKeyword = function (key, new_keyword) {
    var obj = $scope.new_campaign_keywords;
    console.log(key, new_keyword)
    $scope.new_keyword = new_keyword;

    if (!new_keyword)  {
        alert('Invalid input!');
        return;
    };

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(new_keyword)) {
        alert('New keyword in use');
        return;
    };

    //ELSE
    console.log('changes detected');

    obj[new_keyword] = obj[key];
    delete obj[key];
};
```

Use the [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator to remove the old keyword.

Comment: It does make sense thank you, but i dont have this "keyword" object on my template where do you think i can insert it and what property i should use to make it work. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have different options to do this, if you are using ES6 or Typescript you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy only certain properties from an Object

```
let obj= { bar: true, foo1: true, foo2:true};
if(someValidation){
  let { bar, ...rest} = obj;
  obj = {
   ...rest,
   newKey: bar, //or whatever value/key you want
 }
}
```

Now since I see ES5 code only on your code example, I would argue that you are complicating things a little bit, first of all is not a good idea to use a forEach to modify the same array you are iterating over.

Use a map function and do the changes there. You can use the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to eliminate the property you don't want, but is well know that has some performance issues, so let's go with this approach:

```
$scope.campaigns = $scope.campaigns.map(function (v) {
                        a++
                        if (condition) {                      
                           return {
                             newBar: v.bar,
                             foo1: v.foo1,
                             foo2: v.foo2,
                           };
                        }
                        return v;
                    });
```

The other benefit is that now you are making a new array and replacing the current `$scope` variable value once, rather than modifying every single element, since the map return value will be done once the new list is created.

If you need to iterate over the keys dynamically you can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate over them and do the same approach, create a new object, and return it to the map, or return the same initial object.

Comment: I actually have no idea on this haha Im new to java. So can you make it simple, or can you just edit my code and make a few changes on it, that would be nice of you. thanks :)

Comment: @jodelaneferry in the last code example I'm doing the mapping for the campaings varaible you have, It's just like mapping an array in Java, but you return an new *Object Literal* with the new key name